# Saving datetime to MSSQL database from PHP - throws error

Tags: php, sql-server, datetime, yii, odbc

I have PHP web app, which has been deployed to several computers without problem. Just in this one case, I have problem when saving datetime to MSSQL database. The message says:

> SQLSTATE[22007]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server] Conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

I've been always saving datetime format from php to database as `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` (but I need to also save another dates, not just current date). When I make the insert (which throwed error from php) directly through SQL Management studio, it works. Just when it is saved using php, it throws this error.

Now I've edited saving date from php as `date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s')` which works on this particular instance, but I'd rather found a way how to

1. detect the format which will work when saving datetime from php
   to database
2. or change the format (I dont know if this is PHP
   configuration, driver or else).

I've been searching for some way but all I found was how to do conversion, etc.

Comment: So show us some relevant code! [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: If you want to be certain SQL Server will always recognize your supplied datetime value, use the ISO format: `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[.mmm]` or `YYYYMMDD[ hh:mm:ss[.mmm]]`.

Comment: @HoneyBadger I'm using YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[.mmm] now. YYYYMMDD[ hh:mm:ss[.mmm]] works only when making insert in SQL MGMT Studio, not from PHP. Could you please tell me on what depends if SQL Server will recognize the datetime value?

Comment: If you use ISO, nothing affects it. If you use any other format, it depends on `SET DATEFORMAT` or `SET LANGUAGE` setting.

Comment: @HoneyBadger I wanted to get my current setting, so I run `DBCC useroptions` and there's just `dateformat:mdy` so I'm not sure if setting dateformat will help

Comment: You shouldn't have to set dateformat; if you stick to ISO format it will always work, whatever the database settings. It is always helpful if all database your app connects to have the same settings which are known to you. If you don't control the database this may not be easy though. So stick to ISO and you're good.

Comment: @HoneyBadger ok I know now that I should use ISO only. I didn't know it because last about 10 instances were ok with using ODBC datetime from PHP. Just because it won't work on this one instance, I have to rewrite the code (didn't know it would be an issue so I don't have format as a constant somewhere - my fault). It is just strange that the setting is different just on this one instance, and I don't know where to change it. It would be much easier for me right now to just change the config instead of rewriting the code. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: @HoneyBadger I can change database settings, so it shoudn't be problem to set it (if it is issue with database not PHP - I don't know)

Comment: I would start by investigating *why* the settings in this one database are different. If you reset dateformat you might break other functions. That obviously depends entirely on your setup.